# Getting error while submitting a login form using Angular2 and CakePHP in IE10

Tags: php, angular, cakephp

I am new in Angular 2.
I have created a simple login form. I have used Angular 2 in front-end and CakePHP 2.9 in the back-end. 
The login form is working fine in all browser except IE10 and lower version.
The login functionality in Angular 2 side in **login.component.ts** is as follows:-

```
login(event, email_id, password) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let body = JSON.stringify({ email_id, password });
    this.http.post(this.siteURL+'customers/loginCustomer', body, { headers: contentHeaders })
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                let message = response; console.log(message);
                    if(message.json().isloggedin>0)
                    {
                        console.log('Successfully logged In.');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('Error occurred.');
                    }           
            },
      error => {
          console.log(error);
      },
    );
}
```

The site is opening properly in IE10, but while clicking the login button it's giving the following error:- [IE10-ANGULAR2-ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtOrW.png) (Click the link to see the error)

As per my R&D from Google, I have also added the following code in App Controller:-

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    header("crossDomain: true");
```

But still, no luck found.

I have also added **'shim.min.js'** in **'index.html'** of angular 2 , still no luck.

Please let me know that what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you check you are including the correct files as per this link https://christianliebel.com/2016/03/fixing-angular-2-app-ie-9-11/

Comment: and also you need to add access control allow origin in backend side not in frontend

Comment: Thank u for your response. The file you mentioned in "https://christianliebel.com/2016/03/fixing-angular-2-app-ie-9-11/" is already added in index.html . And the access control allow origin i have added in back-end(CakePHP) already as I mentioned.  But still no luck found :(